# Only 10 TCs passed in Minimum Steps by Knight problem. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the logic

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

**Problem**

Given a square chessboard, the initial position of Knight and position of a target. Find out the minimum steps a Knight will take to reach the target position.

Note:
The initial and the target position coordinates of Knight have been given according to 1-base indexing.
Your Task:
You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function minStepToReachTarget() which takes the initial position of Knight (KnightPos), the target position of Knight (TargetPos), and the size of the chessboard (N) as input parameters and returns the minimum number of steps required by the knight to reach from its current position to the given target position.

**Code**

```
class Solution:

    #Function to find out minimum steps Knight needs to reach target position.
    def minStepToReachTarget(self, KnightPos, TargetPos, N):
        #Code here
        step=0
        if KnightPos==TargetPos or N==2:
            return 0
        queue=[KnightPos]
        vis = [KnightPos]
        moves=[[1,2],[1,-2],[-1,2],[-1,-2],[2,1],[2,-1],[-2,1],[-2,-1]]
        while len(queue)>0:
            step+=1
            count=0
            for i in range(len(queue)):
                count+=1
                for m in moves:
                    if [queue[i][0]+m[0],queue[i][1]+m[1]] == TargetPos:
                        return step
                    elif queue[i][0]+m[0]>0 and queue[i][0]+m[0]<=N and queue[i][1]+m[1]>0 and queue[i][1]+m[1]<=N and [queue[i][0]+m[0],queue[i][1]+m[1]] not in vis:
                        queue.append([queue[i][0]+m[0],queue[i][1]+m[1]])
                        vis.append([queue[i][0]+m[0],queue[i][1]+m[1]])
            queue=queue[count:]
```

Comment: Why do you return 0 if N==2?

Comment: What's the point of `vis`? AFAICT it es always equal to `queue`?

Comment: Can you describe in your own word what you think your algorithm is doing?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This question has nothing to do with DSA tag.